# How to create unique list from list with duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, unique

I know how to remove duplicates from a list using set() or two lists, but how do I maintain the same list and add a number at the end for duplicates? I could do it using if, but it´s not pythonic. Thanks guys!!

```
nome_a = ['Anthony','Rudolph', 'Chuck', 'Chuck', 'Chuck', 'Rudolph', 'Bob']
nomes = []

for item in nome_a:  
    if item in nomes:

        if (str(item) + ' 5') in nomes:
            novoitem = str(item) + ' 6'
            nomes.append(novoitem)

        if (str(item) + ' 4') in nomes:
            novoitem = str(item) + ' 5'
            nomes.append(novoitem)

        if (str(item) + ' 3') in nomes:
            novoitem = str(item) + ' 4'
            nomes.append(novoitem)

        if (str(item) + ' 2') in nomes:
            novoitem = str(item) + ' 3'
            nomes.append(novoitem)

        else:
            novoitem = str(item) + ' 2'
            nomes.append(novoitem)

    if item not in nomes:
        nomes.append(item)

print(nomes)
```

Edit(1): Sorry. I edited for clarification.

Comment: I tried running the code and got no output.

Does the list have to maintain the order?

Comment: No, It doesn´t. I edited it for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
names = ['Anthony','Rudolph', 'Chuck', 'Chuck', 'Chuck', 'Rudolph', 'Bob']

answer = []
name_dict = {}

for name in names:
    if name_dict.get(name):
        name_dict[name] += 1
        answer.append('{}_{}'.format(name, name_dict[name]))
    else:
        name_dict[name] = 1
        answer.append(name)

print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
['Anthony', 'Rudolph', 'Chuck', 'Chuck_2', 'Chuck_3', 'Rudolph_2', 'Bob']
```

Comment: Thanks! It never ocurred to me to used a dictionary to solve the problem! Works greate!

Comment: Great - note that you may need to modify the code slightly to take into account upper and lower case names